# Nginx Rewrite rule not working for POST Request

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an nginx server setup with this configuration:

```
location /company {
  rewrite ^/company$ /company/ redirect;
  rewrite ^/company/login$ /company/login/ redirect;
  rewrite ^/company/(.*) /admin/$1 break;
}
```

What I want is redirect the URLs such as `http://localhost/company/login` to `admin/company/login/`. This works fine for a GET request. I am able to see the page.

However, when I am making an AJAX POST Request, to an url: `http://localhost/company/login/login.ajax.php` it is giving me a `404 Error`.

My folder structure is designed in the below fashion:

```
project
|
|_ admin
    |_company
        |_login
        |   |_login.ajax.php
        |_index.php
        |_functions.js
```

My nginx log shows the below error:

```
2018/07/31 14:26:22 [error] 16966#0: *8 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header 
from upstream, client: 192.168.33.1, server: 192.168.33.10, request: "POST /company/login/login.ajax.php HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.33.10",
referrer: "http://192.168.33.10/company/login/"
```

Can anyone suggest how should I configure my nginx rewrite rules so that I get this done?

Comment: Move the `rewrite` rules outside of the `location /company { ... }` block and into the surrounding `server` block.

Comment: The problem might be in the `break` statement after the rewrite, try replacing it with `last`. `rewrite ^/company/(.*) /admin/$1 last;`, you can check the documentation here https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite